# Lebesgue measurable characterisation proof

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $I$ be bounded subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that a $B\subseteq I$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if it satisfies
> $$\lambda^*(I)=\lambda^*(B)+\lambda^*(I\cap B^c)$$

First implications goes from definition of Lebesgue measurability where we just take $I$ as test set.

But I'm stuck with second implication.
I tried to prove it by definition:

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary set. We need to prove $\lambda^*(A) \ge \lambda^*(A \cap B) +\lambda^*(A \cap B^c) $ (other inequality goes from sigma aditivity of outer measure). And I can't even see how to use statement from problem to prove this. Any help?

Comment: Use the seqrch over the site. Defenitely this was answered earlier

Comment: Couldn't find it. I know proof if statement is true for every interval $I$ but not for this one...

Comment: What about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553267/equivalent-definition-of-measurable-set)?

Comment: Hmm... but I am given first interval $I$ and then any subset. What if $\lambda^*(I-B)\neq 0$. How can I use that characterization?