# Prove that every measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the union of a Borel set and a set of measure 0(2)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I was trying to prove this statement:

Prove that every measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the union of a Borel set and a set of measure 0.

And I found its prove here [Prove that Lebesgue measurable set is the union of a Borel measurable set and a set of Lebesgue measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769084/prove-that-lebesgue-measurable-set-is-the-union-of-a-borel-measurable-set-and-a)

But the proof in the link is unclear for me (seems to be not organized) and it uses the first part in the question in the link, So I am wondering is there a nice and easier proof than this? I am studying measure from Royden "Real Analysis" and I have read until theorem 12 on section 2.4. Any help in an organized simple proof will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have taken this theorem:

> [image]

So what can I do after using (iii) in this theorem as a given?

Comment: Is the (2) in the subject a typo or copy-paste error? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: I think u just have to work with the definition of being the inf, make the intersection of the open sets , and then use the fact that its lebesgue measure to get the other set that has measure zero.

Comment: What is Royden's definition of Lebesgue measurability? Is he using the Caratheodory condition applied to Lebesgue outer measure?

Comment: No, it is not a typo, (2) because there is another question by the same title on this site@Bungo

Comment: Although since u want the union i think we will have to work with the closed sets from within, i.e, use the fact that its complement is also lebesgue measure and is approximated by open sets.

Comment: The definition in Royden is: a set $E$ is said to be measurable provided for any set $A$: $$m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$$.@Bungo

Comment: Rudin has a very clear proof of this in his Real and Complex Analysis, 2d edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: For any measurable set $A$ of finite measure, the measure of $A$ is the supremum of the measures of closed sets contained in $A$. Use this to show that for any measurable $A$ (maybe of infinite measure) and $n$, there is a closed $F\subseteq A$ such that $A\setminus F$ has measure smaller than $1/n$.

Comment: and this will be the set of measure zero that the measurable set contains?

Comment: @hopefully: No, since it will have positive measure.

Comment: I have edited my question please check it .... so your hint will be the Borel set? what about the set of measure zero?

Comment: @hopefully: If you take the theorem you cited for granted, then this is immediate by (iv).

Comment: And why $F_{\sigma}$ is considered as a Borel set?

Comment: @hopefully Borel sets are a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, hence closed sets are Borel, and countable unions ($F_\sigma$) of closed sets are Borel.

Comment: got it Thank you very much ...... so the solution is much easier than what is stated in the link above

Comment: @hopefully: I did not read it carefully, but I believe that, presentation aside, the main difference is that the answer you linked does not take the theorem you cite for granted, but instead, contains its proof.